# BETWEEN not working MS Access in PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I have this code which should fetch the all data between specific dates but it's not working. The query works except it keeps ignoring the BETWEEN clause so it's still displaying all data without dates.

```
$statement = Database::prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_applicants FROM student_applicants a WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN (:start_date AND :end_date) AND a.disabled_at IS NULL AND a.disabled_by IS NULL AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.deleted_by IS NULL");
$statement->bindValue(':start_date', '#5/28/2018 12:00:00 AM#');
$statement->bindValue(':end_date', '#5/28/2018 11:59:59 PM#');
$statement->execute();
$student_applicants = $statement->fetch()['total_applicants'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing strings to the query, but using parameters, so you should be passing a time value.

If you were using string concatenation (which you shouldn't do), then your time format would be valid.

Try the following:

```
$statement = Database::prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_applicants FROM student_applicants a WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN (:start_date AND :end_date) AND a.disabled_at IS NULL AND a.disabled_by IS NULL AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.deleted_by IS NULL");
$statement->bindValue(':start_date', strtotime('5/28/2018 12:00:00 AM'));
$statement->bindValue(':end_date', strtotime('5/28/2018 11:59:59 PM'));
$statement->execute();
$student_applicants = $statement->fetch()['total_applicants'];
```